# error; 14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"

Tags: linux, azure, hyper-v

I am attempting to Prepare a CentOS-based virtual machine for Azure, using the following as my guide [Create and upload a CentOS-based Linux VHD - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-centos#centos-70)

Receiving the following error on a Hyper-V guest OS (CentOS 7) when performing a yum update (sudo yum –y update)

**error; 14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"**

1. Created a Azure VM (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, Standard D4s v3; 4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory)
2. Installed Hyper-V 10.0.17763.1
3. Created a Hyper-V guest OS (CentOS-7) from image (CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2009)
4. Configured the following:
5. /etc/sysconfig/network NETWORKING=yes, HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
6. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0; DEVICE=eth0, ONBOOT=yes, BOOTPROTO=dhcp, TYPE=Ethernet, USERCTL=no, PEERDNS=yes, IPV6INIT=no, NM_CONTROLLED=no

On the Hyper-V Host, the status of the guest OS (CentOS 7) Network Adapter is OK and it is connected to the External Virtual Switch

However, on the guest host,  nmcli d shows eth0 unmanaged.
Performed sudo nmcli device et eth0 managed yes

The status of eth0 remains unmanaged.

What other settings can I check or enable so that eth0 will connected and managed? And access the internet?

Answer (score 0):

vim /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There may be firewall that's causing issue. If you use VPN to connect then try without VPN. If issue is not resolved yet then check contents of file /etc/resolv.conf. You will see :
nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx

ping xx.xx.xx.xx , check if it works. If the file is empty or ping doesnt work then add following in the file /etc/resolv.conf:

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`  (or, 8.8.4.4)